# Extract words between double quotes based on position

Tags: java, regex

I have a **single** string that contains several quotes, i.e:

"Bruce Wayne" "43" "male" "Gotham"

I want to create a method using regex that extracts certain values from the String based on their position.

So for example, if I pass the Int values 1 and 3 it should return a String of:
"Bruce Wayne" "male"

Please note the double quotes are part of the String and are escaped characters (\")

Comment: Use a regex with capturing groups and access the groups by index.

Comment: Please see [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

If the number of (possible) groups is known you could use a regular expression like `"(.*?)"\s*"(.*?)"\s*"(.*?)"\s*"(.*?)"` along with `Pattern` and `Matcher` and access the groups by number (group 0 will always be the first match, group 1 will be the first capturing group in the expression and so on).

If the number of groups is not known you could just use expression `"(.*?)"` and use `Matcher#find()` too apply the expression in a loop and collect all the matches (group 0 in that case) into a list. Then use your indices to access the list element (element 1 would be at index 0 then).

Another alternative would be to use `string.replaceAll("^[^\"]*\"|\"[^\"]*$","").split("\"\\s*\"")`, i.e. remove the leading and trailing double quotes with any text before or after and then split on quotes with optional whitespace in between.

Example:

- assume the string `optional crap before "Bruce Wayne" "43" "male" "Gotham" optional crap after`
- `string.replaceAll("^[^\"]*\"|\"[^\"]*$","")` will result in `Bruce Wayne" "43" "male" "Gotham`
- applying `split("\"\\s*\"")` on the result of the step before will yield the array `[Bruce Wayne, 43, male, Gotham]`
- then just access the array elements by index (zero-based)

Answer (score 0):

My function starts at 0. You said that you want 1 and 3 but usually you start at 0 when working with arrays. So to get "Bruce Wayne" you'd ask for `0` not `1`. (you could change that if you'd like though)

```
String[] getParts(String text, int... positions) {
    String results[] = new String[positions.length];

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]*\"").matcher(text);

    for(int i = 0, j = 0; m.find() && j < positions.length; i++) {
        if(i != positions[j]) continue;
        results[j] = m.group();
        j++;
    }

    return results;
}

// Usage
public Test() {

     String[] parts = getParts(" \"Bruce Wayne\" \"43\" \"male\" \"Gotham\" ", 0, 2);
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
     // = ["Bruce Wayne", "male"]

}
```

The method accepts as many parameters as you like.

```
getParts(" \"a\" \"b\" \"c\" \"d\" ", 0, 2, 3); // = a, c, d
// or 
getParts(" \"a\" \"b\" \"c\" \"d\" ", 3); // = d
```

Answer (score 0):

The function to extract words based on position:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.*;

public String getString(String input, int i, int j){
    ArrayList <String> list = new ArrayList <String> ();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\"[^\"]+\")").matcher(input);
    while (m.find()) {
        list.add(m.group(1));
    }
    return list.get(i - 1) + list.get(j - 1);
}
```

Then the words can be extracted like:

```
String input = "\"Bruce Wayne\" \"43\" \"male\" \"Gotham\"";
String res = getString(input, 1, 3);
System.out.println(res);
```

Output:

```
"Bruce Wayne""male"
```